# Generate Random 7 Bytes and Encrypt Them, Getting 8 Byte Result

Tags: bash, macos, encryption, random, openssl

I need to generate seven random bytes, then encrypt them. The encrypted result needs to be eight bytes long. The following line of code does exactly that:

```
openssl rand 7 | openssl enc -des3 -nosalt -k $myPassword
```

However, I need to store the random seven bytes for later use. If I do the following:

```
echo -n $mySevenRandomBytes | openssl enc -des3 -nosalt -k $myPassword
```

The encrypted result is anywhere from 24 bytes long to over a hundred. Does anyone know why passing `openssl rand 7` directly into the `openssl enc` always returns exactly eight bytes, while storing `openssl rand 7` in a variable, then passing that variable to `openssl enc` returns far more?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Another problem was my script header was #!/bin/sh, which Xcode creates by default. I changed it to #!/bin/bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see we have exactly eight bytes long encoding.

```
pwd=ABC
r7b=`openssl rand 7`
echo -n $r7b | od -tx1 -Ano
 26 73 a1 c9 11 fa 71
echo -n $r7b | openssl enc -des3 -nosalt -k $pwd | od -tx1 -Ano
 0f de 41 67 cc 40 5c 34
```